# AngularJS Directive Binding to ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I currently have the following directive:

```
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      value: '=',
    },
    controller: ['$scope',
      function ($scope) {
        $scope.checked = function (...) { ... };
        $scope.toggle = function (...) { ... };
      },
    ],

    template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checked(...)" ng-click="click(...)" />',
  };
```

This works using this syntax:

```
<checker value='shoes' />
<checker value='pants' />
```

However - I'd also like to bind to the `ng-click` event for other purposes. How can I convert to a 'A' directive and still bind to ng-checked and ng-click (without the template) and allow me to use the following syntax:

```
<input type="checkbox" checker ng-click="other()" />
```

Comment: Just open angular source and copy ng-click) element.bind(click) and scope apply is all you need

Comment: if you want isolated scope there must be a template or you have to compile one yourself. Not really clear what you are trying to do